# Get FULL HTML content web page (including javascript content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsoup

After some hours of trying and reading, I'm a bit lost about the title subject.

My problem : I am trying to get the full HTML content (javascript HTML appended/added content) of a single web page. 
What I have already try :

- I used Jsoup, but I had to change because of the fact that jsoup doesn't handle javascript content.
- I used HmtlUtil but I get many errors on the loading of the targeted webpage (like Css error, runtimeError, EcmaError, etc.)
- I used the basic functionnality of Chrome to save the full content webpage and then I used the Jsoup library to get the content i wanted to find. This is the only way I could have get the content I wish get.

So now, the question is, how can I imitate the "save as" function of a browser or how can I, in general, get the full HTML content **first** AND **then** use Jsoup to scan the static final HTML content ?

Thanks a lot for your advise and your help !

Comment: Did you try `$('<div/>').html( $('html').clone() ).html();`

Comment: You can also try with content = $("html").html(); and add the js call at the end of the page...

Comment: I suppose that i have to replace $('html') by $('http://myurl.com/myPage') ?

Comment: use a headless browser

Comment: I wrote a class to do this: It grabs the full HTML page and all scripts, etc. See: https://github.com/JonasCz/save-for-offline/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jonas/tool/saveForOffline/PageSaver.java

Answer (score 2):

I finally get what i wanted to.
I will try to explain for thoose who need some help!

---

So ! The process is composed by two steps :

- First, get the final content HTML (including javascript HTML content, etc.) like if you were visiting the web page and then save it to a simply *file.html*
- Then, we are going to use the Jsoup library to get the wanted content in the saved file, *file.hmtl*.

---

**1 - Get HTML content and save it**

For this step, you will need to download **[phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)** and use it to get the content.
Here is the code to get the target page. 
Just change **myTargetedPage.com** by the URL of the page you want to get and the name of the file **mySaveFile.html**.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
page.open('http://myTargetedPage.com', function () {
    page.evaluate();
    fs.write('mySaveFile.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

As you can see, the file saved is exactly the same as the content load in your browser.

**2 - Extract the content you wanted**

Now, we will use Java and the library [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download) to get or specific content.
in my example, I want to get this part of the web page :

```
/* HTML CONTENT */
<span class="my class" data="data1"></span>
/* HTML CONTENT */
<span class="my class" data="data2"></span>
/* HTML CONTENT */
```

To get this, this code will be fine (don't forget to edit **thePathToYourSavedFile.html** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "thePathToYourSavedFile.html";

    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

    Elements spanList= document.select("span");

   for (Element span: spanList) {
       if(span.attr("class").equals("my class")){
           String data = span.attr("data");
           System.out.println("data : "+data);             
       }
    }       
}
```

---

**Enjoy !**

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice plugin that gives you what you are looking for.  It offers a way to see a page and it's functionality.  It is available for some of the browsers but not all.  Here is the link : http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

P.S. after you install it, there is a little gear on the toolbar located at the top right.  That is where all the functions is at.

Comment: Thank you for sharing and helping, but i am trying to do programmatically so I think this plugin won't help me :-(